# Vue.js - Using v-model on cloned inputs

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am very new to Vue. I have a text input which I am cloning using jquery. However v-model does not take the input from the cloned inputs. It takes input only from the first input.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#add").click(function() { 
        $('#listing').clone(true).insertAfter('#listing'); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

```html
<div>
    <strong>Where are you listed?</strong>
    <input type="text" name="listing" id="listing" class="form-control" v-model="rowInput" v-on="blur: addData">
    <a id="add">Add another</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take care to format the code in your question so that it's easily readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot clone compiled Vue DOM elements – any changes to the DOM must be made by Vue. In other words, you would normally use jQuery or you would use Vue to modify the DOM – you would not normally use both together.

In your case, I would look at using `v-repeat` bound to an array like this:

```
<div v-repeat="listing in listings">
    <strong>Where are you listed?</strong>
    <input type="text" name="listing" id="listing" class="form-control" v-model="listing.value" v-on="blur: addData">
    <a v-on="click: $parent.add">Add another</a>
</div>
```

And in javascript:

```
new Vue({
    data: {
        listings: [{ 
            value: ""
        }]
    },
    methods: {
        add: function (event) {
            this.listings.push({
                value: ""
            });
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: Note, this answer was for Vue 1.X. Under Vue 2.X and newer, you'll need `v-for` instead of `v-repeat`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks David

Comment: Using Vue 2.x not worked with `v-repeat` but with `v-for`. Thanks!